# Perl regex to parse CSS

Tags: regex, perl

I have a typical CSS file format:

```
.success {
    color: #8FA442;
    border: 1px solid #C2D288;
}
.error {
    color: #b3696c;
    border: 1px solid #f7c7c9;
}
```

I want to match every style name and what is in the {}.  I got the {} part and am able to parse the contents easily, however, the problem is that style names can be arrays (e.g. `#contactform .input, .textarea`) and I want to capture the whole thing, in fact everything from the previous closing }.

What I've tried are different variations of

`m/\}(.+)(\{.+?\})/g`

But that grabs the whole file.  If I do

`$doc =~ m/(\w+)\s+(\{.+?\})/g`

that captures each style {} fine but only the last token of the name, so for `#contactform .input, .textarea`, it would only capture `.textarea`.

What to do?

Comment: `(\w+)` captures an unbroken string of *word* characters. Since CSS files can contain comments or comment like strings (such as in IE hacks), chances of coming up with a simplistic regex pattern that deals with all possibilities seem to me to be close to nil.

Answer (score 5):

Use [CSS::DOM](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/CSS%3a%3aDOM) instead. Simplistic regex patterns are unlikely to prove equal to the task.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.012;
use strict;
use warnings;

use CSS::DOM;

my $css = my $sheet = CSS::DOM::parse(do {local $/; <DATA>});
my $rules = $css->cssRules;

for my $rule ( @$rules ) {
    say $rule->selectorText;
}

__DATA__
#contactform  .success {
    color: #8FA442;
    border: 1px solid #C2D288;
}
.error {
    color: #b3696c;
    border: 1px solid #f7c7c9;
}
```

Comment: but just for curiosity sake, can you tell what's wrong with my regex?

Comment: @amphibient Take for example `.class::before{content: "{foo}"}`. You'd select `content: "{foo` as body. And you said yourself you weren't able to match the selector correctly. CSS is a context-free language, which you can't match with simple regexes: you need a *grammar* (Perl regexes can include grammars, but that is a different topic).

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use the one just called [CSS](https://metacpan.org/module/CSS).